# Call different Array base on parameter in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to call the variables base on the parameters pass.

```js
public array1: Array<any> = ['list', 'of','array1'];
public array2: Array<any> = ['list', 'of','array2'];
public array3: Array<any> = ['list', 'of','array3'];
public array4: Array<any> = ['list', 'of','array4'];
public array5: Array<any> = ['list', 'of','array5'];
public array6: Array<any> = ['list', 'of','array6'];

         
    ngOnInit(): void {

     this.useArray(param);

    }

   useArray(param) {

      //if param is array6

      passTheArray(this.array6);

   }
```

This array will be passed to another service to process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the elements.

See the code below.

```
useArray(param) {

    //if param is array6

    passTheArray(this[param]);

}
```

Comment: this is really what I'm looking for.